# Running Redhat/Oracle Linux only application on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, oracle

I'd like to install and run [Oracle Developer Studio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/developerstudio/downloads/index.html) on Ubuntu but the application will only install on Oracle Linux and Redhat. Is there a way to get this application in order to install and run on Ubuntu. [Appimage](http://appimage.org/) perhaps? I'm not sure exactly what it does or if its for this kind of task.

**Edit**

All the techniques that I've tried so far, including the ones suggested, generate a `developerstudio.sh` bundle that launches an installer that refuses to install on Ubuntu.

**Update**

[Version 12.3](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/developerstudio/downloads/solaris-studio-12-3-2333052.html) can be installed by bcat/tar but when I launch the ide it runs, shows a splashscreen and then segfaults, with the message

```
Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ${SPROHOME}/lib/condev/bin/check_update IDE > /dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null
```

[image]

I

Comment: Make a new partition to install CentOS or the developer edition of Redhat

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E60778_01/html/E60741/gljrn.html

Comment: I'm aware of this possibility but I'd hate to install another Linux OS just to run one application. I wonder if there is a workaround that allows me to stay on Ubuntu.

Comment: Or create virtual machine with CentOS or Fedora. Basically you'd use Virtualbox from within Ubuntu

Comment: RedHat uses RPM packages. You might be able to use the `alien` tool to convert the RPM package into an Ubuntu-compatible DEB package. Just guessing though, I have no practical experience with this procedure.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but does anyone know of  an ultra-lightweight VM that I can install on instead of a full-blown VM? All I know of is docker but I don't know if its meant for tasks like this.

Answer (score 3):

You can [install Oracle Developer Studio](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E60778_01/html/E60743/gozqp.html#scrolltoc) for any platform by using the `tar` file.

But be aware that [Oracle says](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E60778_01/html/E60743/gokfg.html#scrolltoc) :

> When you install from a tar file you cannot get support or patches
>   for the product from Oracle.

You may have a better experience installing CentOS or the (free as in beer) Red Hat Developer Edition to a VM or a new partition.

That said, support and patches (similar to Oracle Linux) do not appear to be free, so the `tar` version may be fine.

Comment: Please refer to the edit of the question.

Comment: Well thanks anyway. I followed your advise and that's what I got. The tar file contains a script/bundle that will not install on unapproved OS's. The approach works with version 12.3 of SolarisStudio. Versions 12.4 and 12.5 however generate the script bundle. Unfortunately the version 12.3 binary segfaulted at startup. Thanks again anyway.

Comment: It is deserved. Methinks they are creating artificial walls. I may be close to finding the cause of the segfault with version 12.3

Comment: If you find it, go ahead and post your own answer. I'm going to clean up my previous comments now.